# New-AzActionGroupReceiver How to set up voice call as a New Action Group?

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring, azure-alerts

Reference: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/powershell/module/az.monitor/New-AzActionGroupReceiver?view=azps-3.3.0&viewFallbackFrom=azps-2.6.0

The following code works without any error while I am trying to create a new action group to use with new Alert in Azure Monitor.

```
import-module Az.Monitor
#Setting up action group
$emailaddress = 'first.lastname@domainName.com'
$phoneNumber = '1234567890'
$emailDBA = New-AzActionGroupReceiver -Name 'emailDBA' -EmailAddress $emailaddress
$smsDBA = New-AzActionGroupReceiver -Name 'smsDBA' -SmsReceiver -CountryCode '1' -PhoneNumber $phoneNumber 

Set-AzActionGroup `
    -Name 'notifydbadeadlock' `
    -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
    -ShortName 'deadlock' `
    -Receiver $emailDBA,$smsDBA
```

As per the documentation, I should also be able to add voicemail by using the following code.

`$phoneDBA = New-AzActionGroupReceiver -Name 'phoneDBA' -VoiceCountryCode '1' -VoicePhoneNumber $phoneNumber -VoiceReceiver`

I get an error message.

> New-AzActionGroupReceiver : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'VoiceCountryCode'.
>   At line:1 char:56
>   + ...  New-AzActionGroupReceiver -Name 'phoneDBA' -VoiceCountryCode '1' -Vo ...
>   +                                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-AzActionGroupReceiver], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Insights.ActionGroups.NewAzureRmActionGroupReceiverCommand

I did update the module `Az.Monitor`.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. After some research, I found that you should use [powershell v6](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/tag/v6.2.4), then install [Az.Monitor, version 1.5.0](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az.Monitor/1.5.0), it can work well.

Steps as below:

1.Nav to the [powershell v6](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/tag/v6.2.4) site -> then scroll down to the end of the page -> download the proper one, then install it locally.

2.Find the powershell v6 from your pc(I'm using win10, just click the "Start" menu -> then you can find powershell v6). Then open it as administrator right -> install the [Az.Monitor, version 1.5.0](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az.Monitor/1.5.0). A screenshot as below:

[image]

3.Then you can use this command `get-help New-AzActionGroupReceiver -Detailed` to check if the parameter `VoiceCountryCode` is available now:

[image]

4.Then the command you're using can work. And also let me know if you still have more issues.

**Note:**

If you don't install powershell v6 locally, another simple way is that you can use cloud-shell of powershell from azure portal:

[image]

Comment: Worked perfectly, thx. If I am looking at the action group properties under status column it shows `subscribed` for email & sms but not for voice. But voice works in my test.